# Bash, sed: replacing pattern with multiline file content

Tags: bash, sed

if I have file named some_file, with content as follows:

```
first line 
second line 
third line
```

and inside script:

```
VAR1="first line\nsecond line\nthird line"
VAR2="`cat some_file`"
```

I expect VAR1 and VAR2 to be the same, but it is obviously not the case according to the sed:

```
sed "s/^a/${VAR1}/" some_another_file # this is OK
sed "s/^a/${VAR2}/" some_another_file # this fail with syntactic error
```

I suppose that newline representation is somehow different, but i can't find any way how to make VAR2 equal to VAR1.

thanks in advance

Comment: @user665920: Select code/commands in the editor and press ctrl+k

Comment: Please submit UNIX and GNU/Linux related questions on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change VAR1 to:

```
VAR1=$(echo -e "first line\nsecond line\nthird line")
```

Then test them:

```
$ [ "$VAR1" == "$VAR2" ] && echo equal
equal
```

Update:

To get sed to work, change VAR2 so that it has "\n"s instead of newline characters.

```
VAR2=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' some_file)
sed "s/^a/${VAR2}/" file
```

Comment: OK, but I need it the other way round. VAR1 in the original form is fine for sed, but VAR2 with newline representation as it has causes syntactic error.

Comment: Then change VAR2 to: `VAR2=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' some_file)`

Comment: BTW, the original code only works with an outright non-POSIX-compliant version of `echo` and a `test` (`[`) with non-POSIX extensions. A POSIX-compliant `echo -e` will print `-e` on its output (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), and a baseline-POSIX `test` will only recognize `=`, not `==`, as a string comparison operator.

Comment: Consider using `printf '%b\n' "content here"` where you might otherwise use the noncompliant `echo -e "content here"`.

Answer (score 4):

This will read in the file and replace the line with its contents:

```
sed -e '/^a/{r some_file' -e 'd}' some_another_file
```